# I cant break my foreach with ajax inside

Tags: arrays, foreach, break

I have this:

```
var addresses_tmp = addresses.slice();
    var final_addresses = [];
    addresses.forEach(function (current_address, i) {
        var near_addresses = [];
        near_addresses.push(current_address);
        addresses_tmp.forEach(function (next_address, j) {
            if (current_address.address.info.code != next_address.address.info.code) {
                var data = {
                    key             : $scope.MicrosoftKey,
                    optmz           : "distance",
                    routeAttributes : "routePath"
                }
                data["wp.0"] = current_address.address.location.lat + "," + current_address.address.location.lng;
                data["wp.1"] = next_address.address.location.lat + "," + next_address.address.location.lng;
                ajax.sendApiRequest(data, "GET", "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving", is_url=true).then(
                    function(response) {
                        var distance = response.data.resourceSets[0].resources[0].travelDistance;
                        if (distance < 0.020) {
                            near_addresses.push(next_address);
                            addresses_tmp.splice(j, 1);
                        }
                        if (j == addresses.length - 1) {
                            final_addresses.push(near_addresses);
                            if (near_addresses.length == 1) {
                                addresses_tmp.splice(j, 1);
                            }
                            addresses_tmp.splice(i, 1);

                        }

                        // if (count == addresses.length * addresses.length) {
                        //     console.log("ya he acabado todasssss")

                        // }
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        console.log("error", error);
                    }
                )
            }
        })
    })
```

And I would like to break all function when the first foreach and the second foreach are finished but I cant put if condition to do this.

As I have ajax inside the second foreach, my variables are crazy so I cant put an if condition to break it.

I need to do this because I am compare two arrays and getting distance between two points (one in the first array and second in the other array)

Comment: I change my code and I use recursive, and it works!